# Rails Elastic Beanstalk deploy - sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, sqlite, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a rails app to elastic beanstalk but getting an error.

```
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
ERROR: [Instance: i-053f6b1dfef0f156b] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...arrierwave.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/app/ondeck/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace). 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-053f6b1dfef0f156b'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.                                

ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

Don't know why I am getting this Carrierwave error. I have that file to work with S3 to upload photos.

carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
        provider: "AWS",
        aws_access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
        aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
    }
    config.fog_directory = ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]
end
```

environment.rb

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Here is the log:

[image]

**EDIT**
HERE:

```
 ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
  /var/app/ondeck/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /var/app/ondeck/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  Tasks: TOP => environment
```

**EDIT2**
my part of the gem file;

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

and I created the RDS with postgresql. 
database.yml file;

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>#db/production.sqlite3
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

getting an error of ;

```
ERROR: [Instance: i-053f6b1dfef0f156b] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
```

why should I add gem sqlite3?, I have it already in development and should use in production. That is how Heroku works. I thought the same for elastic beanstalk

Comment: See the log: `/var/log/eb-activity.log`. What does it say?

Comment: sorry, how do I go there?

Comment: As the message says: `using console or EB CLI`. Or, just google it.

Comment: Ok, saw the problem and try to solve it. Thank you

Comment: but the problem is I have declared in application.yml file

Comment: Do you have them set up for `production` environment?

Comment: Now I am getting this error; `Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...sqlite3'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found out two problems:

1. AWS environment variables missing (required by CarrierWave) in the environment (which prevents `rake assets:precompile` during the creation).
2. Missing sqlite3 in Gemfile's production (which is required by EB).

You need to **configure AWS environment variables** when creating the environment:

```
eb create [app_name] -v --envvars AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=[access_key], AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET=[key_secret]`
```

Event though you are using PostgreSQL as your database in [AWS RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby.rds.html#create_deploy_Ruby.rds.newDB), and you have specified it in `Gemfile` and `database.yml`, EB still requires sqlite3. Maybe for its own usage. So just add sqlite3 to Gemfile's production block.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<<: *default` from the first line of your `production:` in your database.yml file. 
It its causing you chaos b/c in default you're saying sqlite3 then in the next 5 lines you're providing postgres info.